# How to remove installation on startup in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, boot, installation, windows-registry

I have tried to install SVNNotifier, but interrupted in middle of installation process and deleted installation file.
And after when I start system I always receive small windows to continue installation.
I tried delete from startup menu, but after restart in re-created.
I suppose that something need fix in registry, but not sure what exactly. Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this](http://www.how-to-uninstall-program.com/uninstaller/uninstall-SVN-Notifier-1-8-3-SVN-Notifier-1-8-3-removal-SVN-Notifier-1-8-3-windows-uninstaller.html) guide, hope this solves your problem.

Comment: You should include the contents of your linked answer in your answer... at least the pertinent parts. (just in case the link ever dies)

Answer (score 2):

I use a program called [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) -- the free version.  It will not only run the application-specific uninstaller program, but also search for and remove any registry files associated with it that the uninstaller left behind.

Since you stopped the install before it was completed, there may not be an actual uninstall program.  Also, even Revo Uninstaller may not see that the program is "installed", and therefore not give you the option to uninstall.

My suggestion would be to download and install the free version of Revo, then download and reinstall the SVNNotifier application.  Once you have both installed, then run Revo to uninstall.  It should find all the associated leftovers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this which is quick way to do it ..

- Install and run http://www.ccleaner.com
- Scan the registry, do a backup when prompted and fix all
- In CCleaner goto Tools, startup and find the svn program and disable the entry

Reboot and test!

Comment: Ramhound, as you seem to have downgrade every post i did today i will point out something, i mentioned ccleaner to do items 2 and 3. If you are so knowledgeable, then maybe you should spend more time helping the people in trouble and less time wasting my afternoon trying to help others ...

Comment: While I did vote down pretty much every post you made, I would argue most of them deserved it, because most were one or two sentences and worst yet just repeated what was already said.